# WordPress: Query post by title and author

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I'm trying to create a custom request on a WordPress website to find a post by it's title and author (the match can be case insensitive, but has to be an exact match).

Up to now, I found how to [get a post by it's title](https://tommcfarlin.com/get-post-content-by-title/) even though you can't seem to add parameters such as the author, and this leads to security issues as well.

I also looked into the [WP_Query parameters here](https://gist.github.com/luetkemj/2023628) but there doesn't seem to be a post_title parameter. We can still perform a search by author though.

I couldn't find an example to query only the posts matching the author and title I'm looking for.

Does anyone know how to create such a query?
I wrote this code but can't get the result I expect because 'post_title' just doesn't exist, and 'name' searches for the slug:

```
$args = array(
    'post_title'    => $title
    'author'        => $WP_user->id
);

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    //DO STUFF HERE
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85373/query-by-post-title

They use 'name' instead of 'post_title'

Comment: Well, as said above, the problem with 'name' is that it's actually the slug, and not the title, which doesn't help as it's different, but thanks for the link.